# Mysql Cluster using Docker: Error 708 'No more attribute metadata records (increase MaxNoOfAttributes)'

Tags: docker, mysql-cluster

I'm setting up a mysql cluster using Docker. I have 1 management node, 2 data nodes, and 2 sql nodes. When I create a database on one sql node, it gets replicated to the other sql node which is perfectly fine.

The problem is when I import an sql file which contains many tables into one sql node, I encounter the error: 'No more attribute metadata records (increase MaxNoOfAttributes)'. I tried increasing the value of  MaxNoOfAttributes to its maximum (4294967039), and also increasing the value of MaxNoOfTables to its maximum (20320), restarted the management node container, then tried again. But I'm still getting the same error. Here's my config.ini file:

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataMemory=5G
IndexMemory=64M
MaxNoOfTables = 20320
MaxNoOfAttributes = 4294967039
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=5242

[mysqld default]

[ndb_mgmd default]

[tcp default]

[ndb_mgmd]
NodeId=2
hostname=180.168.0.2

[ndbd]
NodeId=3
hostname=180.168.0.3
DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndbd]
NodeId=4
HostName=180.168.0.4
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[mysqld]
NodeId=5
hostname=180.168.0.10

[mysqld]
NodeId=6
hostname=180.168.0.11
```

The sql file contains more than 90 tables.

I've been searching this for quite a while now and I can't seem to find a working solution. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@swrcmsdbm:/# /usr/sbin/ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini --initial

MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.7.32 ndb-7.6.16

root@swrcmsdbm:/# usr/bin/ndb_config -q MaxNoOfAttributes

2560000 2560000
```

Comment: You should explain why your commands help answering the question.